# Python 3: Append integers on a list with while True loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

> Task 4
>
> Create a empty list purchase_amounts
> populate the list with user input for the price of items  continue adding to list with while until "done" is entered
>
> can use while True: with break
>
> print purchase_amounts

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#[ ] complete the Register Input task above
purchase_amounts=[]
purchase_amounts.append(input("Enter the prices: "))
while True:
    if input("Enter the prices: ") != "done":
        purchase_amounts.append(input("Enter the prices: "))
    else:
        break
print(purchase_amounts)
```

But it gives me a very strange output like this:

> Enter the prices: 2222222
>
> Enter the prices: 1
>
> Enter the prices: 2
>
> Enter the prices: 3
>
> Enter the prices: done
>
> Enter the prices: done
>
> ['2222222', '2', 'done']

Does anybody know why it overwrites the second, fourth and fifth input and it does not add the values to the list? Many thanks!

Comment: You need to restructure that a bit. `input()` returns the string entered by the user. In the while loop, you discard the value if it is not equal to "done", and prompt user again.

So, store the value somewhere, and then compare against that (stored) value.

Comment: It is because, you are calling the input function twice. Store the input in a local variable and compare the local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking input too many times.

You should only take input only once per loop by calling `input()` & then add to the list. You probably want to turn the input into a number with `float` as well.

```
purchase_amounts=[]
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter the prices: ")
    if user_input != "done":
        purchase_amounts.append(float(user_input))
    else:
        break
print(purchase_amounts)
```

Output:

```
Enter the prices: 12
Enter the prices: 13
Enter the prices: done
[12, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 input(), but actually use only one. Check the comments:

```
while True:
    if input("Enter the prices: ") != "done":                   #Here you only compare the input with "done" but you don't do anything with it
        purchase_amounts.append(input("Enter the prices: "))    #here you ask for a second input
```

You can ask for the input only once and keep it in a variable:

```
while True:
    value_input = input("Enter the prices: ")
    if value_input != "done":                   
        purchase_amounts.append(value_input)    
    else:
        break
```

PS: you might want to convert the string into int, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try use test case separately from IF.

Please notice, python way for != is `not (test case)`

```
purchase_amounts=[]
# purchase_amounts.append(input("Enter the prices: ")) <- this can be sacked
while True:
    test_case = input("Enter the prices: ")
    if not test_case == "done":
        purchase_amounts.append(input("Enter the prices: "))
    else:
        break
print(purchase_amounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
purchase_amounts=[]
while True:
    a=input("Enter price of Items :")
    if a=='Done':
        break
    else:
        purchase_amounts.append(a)

print(purchase_amounts)
```